# @nuxtjs/i18n works in development(dev) but fails in production (build)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm using "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.4" with the following config:

```
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    locale: "fa",
    messages: {
        en: {
            Categories: "Categories",
        },
        fa: {
            Categories: "دسته‌بندی‌ها",
        },
    },
}));
```

it works pretty good in dev but fails in build.

the error messages that appears in browser:
**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 't')**

the error disappeared when i delete all $t functions or delete the messages block like this:
`messages: {}`

**any suggestion can be helpful.**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a minimal reproduction for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've used another version of the library. everything magically worked.

Comment: @MohsenDastaran what version? Because I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.4"